# Why is NLTK's Text.similar() returning None?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

Right now I am using similar() method from nltk.
But is is not working as expected. Please see below piece of code:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize;
import nltk;
text = """
The girl is very pretty.
""";
text = nltk.Text(word_tokenize(text));
text.similar('beautiful');  #it returns "no matches" but pretty is synonym of beautiful.
```

Am I using wrong approach? Or is there any other? Please help me.

Comment: are you just looking for a similarity metric on a per word basis, or sentence level?

Comment: In some cases, I have to find similarity of a phrase and and sometimes for a word. e.g. if in data, I have a word <..something...> **"Exceptions"** <..something..>, then by given word: **"exclusion"** as input, algo should tell me yes its synonym is present in given data set and that is **"Exceptions"**.

Answer (score 2):

The NLTK `Text` class' `similar()` method uses [Distributional Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics).

The `help()` on the method states:

```
similar(word, num=20) method of nltk.text.Text instance
    Distributional similarity: find other words which appear in the
    same contexts as the specified word; list most similar words first.
```

Looking [in the source code](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html), `similar()` uses an instantiation of the `ContextIndex` class to find words with similar semantic windows. By default, it uses a +/- 1 word window.

If we extend your example with additional words to give similar semantic windows for "pretty" and "beautiful", we will get the result you are looking for.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
import nltk
text = "The girl is pretty isn't she? The girl is beautiful isn't she?"
text = nltk.Text(word_tokenize(text))
text.similar('pretty')
# prints beautiful
```

So it seems you need to have more context in your text to give meaningful results.

Comment: Well, I will have raw data from user input. So, there is a possibility that there  will be less context in given input. Can you suggest me any other approach other than nltk. May be any other python package..

Comment: you may want to use pretrained models for word similarity such as word2vec using the gensim package with GoogleNews (see http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/), then you can just call `most_similar()` https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html